# Samba running slow between OS-X and Fedora Core

Tags: mac-osx, samba, fedora

I've got a local web development server set up in my house running FC 12. It is running samba and I map to a defined area to do web development. It has been fast ever since I set it up over 6 months ago and I use it on a daily basis. Just recently, I'm noticing extremely long load times when I attempt to read directories and open files from the share (30+ seconds on a regular basis). I rebooted the server, updated samba to 3.4.9-60.fc12, rebooted the server again, and I'm still seeing the same issues. I've looked over some of the samba logs and I'm not sure what I should be looking for. I can't think of anything that has changed on the development server (or my Mac, for that matter) that would have caused any issues.

Any suggestions? Things I should look for in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Samba has two daemons, smbd and nmbd, make sure you check the logs for both.

My favourite publisher: http://oreilly.com/catalog/samba/chapter/book/ch09_01.html

Sometimes a network capture gives clues about possible sources of problems. Wireshark is handy for this.